# How do I create a button with Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, button, kivy

I am hoping to eventually create a button to pause/start/end  a pong app I built as a learning exercise. However, to understand the basics of how to create a button in the first place, and assign a response to it I am just wanting to create a button that notifies me every time the button state changes.  Here is the python code I have so far:

```
import kivy.uix.button as kb
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Button_Widget(Widget):
    def callback(instance, value):
        print('The button <%s> state is <%s>' % (instance, value))

    btn1 = kb.Button(text='Hello World 1')
    btn1.bind(on_press=callback)

class ButtonApp(App):
    def build(self):
        button = Button_Widget()
        return button
```

with the associated kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Button_Widget>:
    size: 100, 100
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos = self.pos
            size = self.size
```

So far the only resources I have found are these ([1](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label) and [2](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button)) Kivy turorials, which aren't too helpful.  Or at least, I don't understand their language enough yet for them to be useful

Comment: whats is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see the simplest code to create a button in kivy

```
   from kivy.app import App
   from kivy.uix.button import Button
   class your_app_name(App):
       def build(self):
           button = Button(text="Button")
           return button
   your_app_name().run()
```

You can also add command or event to a button by adding on_press= function_name

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

In the class Button_Widget(), you have to override the constructor, `__init__()` so that you can add the button widget to the root widget. Please refer to the example for details.

## References

[Programming Guide » Kivy Basics » Create an application](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html#create-an-application)

[Programming Guide » Kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

[Kivy Language](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file)

[Event dispatcher » bind()](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind) Bind an event type or a property to a callback.

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy.uix.button as kb
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Button_Widget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Button_Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        btn1 = kb.Button(text='Hello World 1')
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        self.add_widget(btn1)

    def callback(self, instance):
        print('The button %s state is <%s>' % (instance, instance.state))


class ButtonApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button_Widget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ButtonApp().run()
```

### button.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<Button_Widget>:
    size: 100, 100
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

## Output

[image: Img01]